# Tableau link to worksheet

Tags: hyperlink, tableau-api, worksheet

I would like dashboard to link to worksheet. Unfortunately, these instructions show how to link to webpage, or file on server.

http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/actions_url.html

How to link to worksheet?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a Filter action. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/actions_filter.html Without more information, I'm not sure what your goal is.

Comment: @Bernardo I'll try out some other solutions, else I'll post more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of the link?
If you have a whole lot of worksheets and just want to open the one that you look at in the dashboard, you can cllick the small "go to" icon in the top right corner of the graph.

[image]

To actually create an action that links to a worksheet is not possible and doesn't seem to make sense, since the URL action is meant to create a link based on a certain value in your data, however no matter what data is displayed, you will always end on the same graph.

In case you want to further investgate certain data you select, you could create a filter in the same dialogue that filters other graphs in your dashboard based on the values you select.

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll research this